# Deleting columns in csv file based on column number/ position in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I began by trying to merge 2 csv files into one larger file. This is my code to achieve this:

```
import glob
path = r'Z:/Mike/Matt/' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*timeseries.csv')
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_, axis=1) #axis = 1 appends horizontally
frame.to_csv('emotion_timeseries.csv')
```

This creates one large csv file like I had wanted, however, when I try to read "frame" in the spyder console is also gives the following error:

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

I wasn't too concerned since I was able to get the csv file in the end. Now I am trying to delete certain columns from the above csv.

I have the following columns: "subject, trial, emotion, response, subject, trial, emotion, response". These columns contain different, distinct information. I would like to get rid of the second subject column that appears, along with the second trial column that appears.

I tried using the following code to do so:

```
frame.drop(df.columns[[4,5]], axis=1, inplace=True)
frame.to_csv('emotion_cleaner_timeseries.csv')
```

I get the following error: IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5

I was hoping the above code would drop the 5th and 6th columns leaving me with "subject, trial, emotion, response, emotion, response".

I have a feeling I am using this command incorrectly and I was hoping someone would be able to help me achieve this goal. Thank you in advance for your help and let me know if you have any questions.